# How show and zoom Google Map v3 after click on elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I end up with this code to show google map:

```
<script>
function init_map() {

    // Create an array of styles.
    var styles = [
        {
            "featureType": "water",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "color": "red"
                },
                {
                    "lightness": 25
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    var myOptions = {
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: ['Map']
        },
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.514459, 0.13461),
        zoom:3,
        disableDefaultUI: false,
        mapTypeId: 'Map',
        scrollwheel: false,
        navigationControl: true,
        scaleControl: true,
    };

    var div = document.getElementById('gmap_canvas');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(div, myOptions);
    var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: 'Map' });
    map.mapTypes.set('Map', styledMapType);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        //position: new google.maps.LatLng(56.6789471,-0.34535),
        icon: "images/marker.png"
    });
    var markers = [
        ['One', 11.232214,122.155547],
        ['Two', 39.555535,-87.5462367],
        ['Three', 48.3563671,-1.34554825],

    ];

    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            icon: "images/ico.png",
            title: markers[i][0]
        });
    }
}

if (document.getElementById("gmap_canvas")) {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
}
```

This code above creates google map with mulitple points (one, two, three).

And what i want to do, is to have a list of this contact points like:

```
<div class="point">Contact ONE</div>
<div class="point">Contact TWO</div>
<div class="point">Contact THREE</div>
```

And when i click this contact map should zoom to this point.
I found this, but example shows only one point, and also event is fired on marker click, not custom Html element.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `map` variable to global and define a global variable to a marker array (in the sample : `markerArr`).(Outside the `init_map()` function):

```
 <script>
 var map;
 var markerArr = [];
 function init_map() {...
 ...
```

Then in the for loop add each marker to this array:

```
 for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        icon: "images/ico.png",
        title: markers[i][0]
    });
    markerArr.push(marker); // Add the marker to the array
 }
```

Then create a simple function with an integer param, let's call it `jumpToMarker`, where we can zoom and jump to the selected marker.:

```
function jumpToMarker(cnt){
    map.panTo(markerArr[cnt].getPosition());
    map.setZoom(4);
}
```

Finally set the divs and their onclick event in the DOM, after the map's div:

```
<div class="point"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="jumpToMarker(0)">Contact ONE</a></div>
<div class="point"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="jumpToMarker(1)">Contact TWO</a></div>
<div class="point"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="jumpToMarker(2)">Contact THREE</a></div>
```

Hope this helps!